# Running a script containing `document.write` inside a React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Precursor: I've been asked to implement a 3rd party widget which is loaded through a script tag.

This script is implemented by placing `<script src="https://some.domain/script.js" />` where you want it to be executed. It writes the widget to that section of the DOM on load; including loading some jquery libraries.

**Script start:**

```js
  document.write("<!â€“- jQuery and jQuery UI are a required...
```

The script contains a form, which includes a dynamic token, so it's not something I can just replicate as `jsx`.

I've tried using an iFrame, which works up to submission, whereupon the 3rd party page attempts to open. This happens, not in a new tab, but inside the iFrame. Not only that, but `X-Frame-Options` are set to `sameorigin`. So, even if I could possibly make an iFrame solution work, it ends up not working.

Since `document.write` is not going to work in React, options like react-helmet, react-load-script, or hooks are out.

I'm hoping there's a way to achieve this which doesn't involve getting devs from this 3rd party vendor involved to work around the issues (deadline looming).

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've requested my 3rd party provider update their approach. `document.write` has been under the microscope for quite some time and using it at this point in time just doesn't cut it. More info:

https://web.dev/no-document-write/

> Avoid document.write() #
> Remove all uses of document.write() in your code. If it's being used to inject third-party scripts, try using asynchronous loading instead.
>
> If third-party code is using document.write(), ask the provider to support asynchronous loading.